# Find partitions based on data

Tags: discrete-mathematics, discrete-optimization, decision-trees

I have a set of vectors $V = (v_1, v_2, \cdots, v_i, \cdots, v_n), v_n \in \mathbb{R}^d$ and a partition annotation $L_i$ for each vector $L_i \in \{1, 2, \cdots, K \}$.

My goal is to partition $V$ only based on linear rules per dimension(intersections of axis-aligned hyperplanes) such that the final output matches the annotation.

For example, $v_1 = (1, 0, 1), v_2 = (2, 2, 1), v_3 = (1, 1, 2), L_1=1, L_2=2, L_3=3$.

Then i can find a rule $(v_{i0} > 2 ) \to 2, (v_{i0} < 2 \& v_{i1} < 1) \to 1, (v_{i0} < 2 \& v_{i1} \geq 1) \to 3$ which matches the annotation.

For a general dataset, how can one determine if there exists a list decision rule that matches the annotation?  Also if there don't exist, how can one find a most similar list decision rule such that the annotations are as close as possible?

Comment: Does "based on linear rules" mean "intersections of axis-aligned hyperplanes" like your example, or more broadly "intersections of hyperplanes," or something even broader?

Comment: ah, "intersections of axis-aligned hyperplanes" is what I mean by linear rules. thanks for the more precise description @angryavian

Comment: Search for "optimal classification trees"

Comment: Thanks for the point, indeed it overlaps with the problem a lot, but maybe focus on the determination problem? Is there any fast way to check it it is possible even?

Comment: The OCT approach will find a classification tree with zero error if one exists.

Comment: It would, but is there anyway one can do better than that by determining alone?

Comment: If you mean you want to determine whether a tree with zero error exists without minimizing error, you can stop early if the dual lower bound becomes positive.

Comment: Good point… well I’ll probably think more of it without using MIP technique, as I obtain less insight on the problem by doing that